# Как заполнить datePicker Java Selenium/Selenide

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как заполнить дату в datePicker?

Варианты :

```
$(By.cssSelector("[type='date']")).setValue("2018-06-01");
$(By.cssSelector("[type='date']")).sendKeys("2018-06-01");
```

Не срабатывают. Как еще можно заполнить данное поле?

```
<div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputMainContent exportContent">
    <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputContentArea exportContentArea">
        <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInputArea"><input type="date"
                                                                   class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput"
                                                                   jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0"
                                                                   value="" data-initial-value=""></div>
        <div class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputUnderline exportUnderline"></div>
        <div jsname="XmnwAc"
             class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputFocusUnderline exportFocusUnderline animationInitialized"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: DataPicker]

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35855868/3841429)

Answer (score 2):

Проще всего вызвать нужную JavaScript функцию.

Вот хороший ответ: http://barancev.github.io/how-to-set-datepicker-value/